# How to fix 'Invalid App ID' error in Facebook SDK Share dialog with non-developer account?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I have made use of facebooks sdk to use their "Share" dialog. I created a button that once clicked, opens up a window which allows the user to select reciepients and add a message if they like before the click send.

The issue that I have somewhat figured out is if I am not using the email that is associated with my facebook developers account, when the dialog window opens and I login with a different facebook account that isnt the same as my developers account I get the following error message:

```
error_code: 1
error_msg: "kError 1349040: Invalid App ID: The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID."
```

[image: Facebook Share Dialog Window]

Would anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The app id you are using is probably still in developer mode.

Comment: I was assuming that too. I will try to change it from developer to live. I was trying to do so before but It requires business verification. Why is that? Is there anyway to bypass that?